# RestKit in iOS - How to send in iOS & receive in java?

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, rest, restkit

I m new to RESTful Webservices in iOS and in Java. I read really a lot but i dont get definitiv answer how to SEND & RECEIVE a POST request in iOS & Handle that in Java.

My Situation is this:

I want to create a user on serverside. On Clientside i got for that 3 Objects that saves information (User, Usersdevice & Usersmembership). I read a lot about Objectmapping but I cant relate it with a practical example.

Seconde one is how to handle that POST on serverside with Java(Jersey) as RE.

Iknow that are two qeustions but I really need to know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to post a  snippet of your code and clarify which restkit version uses. seems a bit outdated.

Also read the newest Object Mapping guide in order to leverage RestKit taking care if you want the KVC mapping or not. It could be tricky!!!

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping

First of all you have to determine your base URL:

```
 RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourURL.com]];
```

A method to download articles using RK object mapping:

```
- (void)loadArticles{
        RKObjectMapping* articleMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Article class]];
        [articleMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ 
            @"title": @"title",
            @"body": @"body",
            @"author": @"author",
            @"publication_date": @"publicationDate"
        }];
        RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:articleMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"articles" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    NSString * stringURL = @"/articles/";
    [RKObjectManager.sharedManager getObjectsAtPath:stringURL parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
            RKLogInfo(@"Load collection of Articles: %@", mappingResult.array);
        } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
        }];

        [objectRequestOperation start];
    }
```

In order to map this JSON

```
{ "articles": [
{ "title": "RestKit Object Mapping Intro",
  "body": "This article details how to use RestKit object mapping...",
  "author": "Blake Watters",
  "publication_date": "7/4/2011"
},
{ "title": "RestKit 1.0 Released",
  "body": "RestKit 1.0 has been released to much fanfare across the galaxy...",
  "author": "Blake Watters",
  "publication_date": "9/4/2011"
}]
```

}

Comment: I use RKv0.20.x. Im new to RK and i really could need a sample code from scatch of.. could you provide this?